# Display a pop-up on radio button click

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery

Please let me know how to open a pop-up on click of a radio button using JQuery. 
Currently Im using a the following code for a radio button using Spring MVC and JSTL

```
<label class = "">
 <form:radiobutton path = "" value = "" onchange= ""/>
<label class = "" style = ""> <spring:message code ="" /></label>
</label>
```

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this will solve your problem.

```
onchange= "window.open("http://www.stackoverflow.com",width=200,height=100); "/>
```

**EDIT1:** Removing the `hide` class does the trick.

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function () {       
                $('#r').removeClass("hide");
    });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<input type='radio'>SO
<div id="r" selectOption="#" class="modal hide" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" style=" background-color:#ccc; height: 100px;width: 350px"></div>
```

**EDIT2:**

If you check my html code, you will see an ***id for div named as "r" (unique selector) and class name "hide" prevent the div to be displayed.***  Therefore the div is hidden.

When the radio button is click, using [removeClass](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) ***we're removing the class "hide" this make the div visible.***

Check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/2nY89/68/)

Hope you understand.

Comment: open a JQuery Dialogue pop-up on click of a radio button i.e <div selectOption="#" class="modal hide" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" style="margin-top: -150px; width: 350px" >

Comment: @ronan Check my answer, you will get some idea. I will try to do a fiddle.

Comment: Thanks a lot but I did not understand your JQuery code
What does  $('#r').removeClass("hide"); mean ? 
I want to display the div id r

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming you mean a new window by `pop-up`?

The following code will open a new window with the URL when the status of the radio button changes. You can use `click` if you like...

```
$("#pop").change(function() {
    window.open("http://www.google.com");
});

<input type="radio" id="pop" value="yes">
```

[**JSFiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/neo108/4qyHv/8/)

Comment: Thanks 
The best is to open a JQuery Dialogue pop-up on click of a radio button 
i.e 
<div selectOption="#" class="modal hide" tabindex="-1"  role="dialog" style="margin-top: -150px; width: 350px" >

Answer (score 2):

you mean like this? **[CLICK HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/2nY89/65/)**

**HTML**

```
<input type='radio' id='myRadio'>Radio button
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#myRadio').click(function()
    {
        alert("Clicked");
    });
});
```